# Синонимизировать [xmpp] и [jabber]

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, статус-завершено, синонимы-меток

[jabber](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jabber)- оригинальное название для протокола [xmpp](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xmpp). С другой стороны, это ещё и сервер по обмену сообщений [Jabber.org](http://Jabber.org)

На en SO: это [синонимы](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xmpp/synonyms). То есть, там jabber метка является синонимом для xmpp.

Предлагаю и у нас их синонимизировать.

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, какую из меток вы предлагаете сделать основной?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky видимо, по образу и подобию enSO и по формальному названию протокола — xmpp

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky ага, xmpp  основной.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky up

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Готово. Теперь [jabber](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jabber) является синонимом основной метки [xmpp](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xmpp)

Answer (score 1):

Возможно их стоит синонимизировать, но на мой взгляд не стоит идти по образу и подобию enSO, в России (и странах СНГ) хорошо известен именно `jabber` и почти не известен  `xmpp`, поэтому либо их не синонимизировать, либо поставить именно `jabber` основной меткой.

Например, яндекс находит 45 млн. результатов для `jabber` и только 5 млн. для  `xmpp` (если искать в гугле на английском такой разницы нет). ИМХО.

Comment: Потому что обычные пользователи ищут именно сервер с точки зрения обычного клиента (то есть для общения). На SO вопросы же именно программистские/админские.

Comment: Это понятно, но админы точно так же часто могут искать ответы по настройке сервера, возможно вопросов по серверам будет больше чем по протоколам. Хотя... посмотрел вопрос в сумме менее 40, возможно нет никакой разницы

Comment: Вот пусть синонимизация знакомит людей с термином xmpp :D Если заботиться о гуглинге, то «jabber/джаббер» почти наверняка будут упомянуты в тексте вопроса и они всё равно будут успешно гуглиться